# Store an array value from the user and print it where array it stored (using only array and forloop)

Tags: c, arrays, loops, for-loop

I've made a program that asks how many elements should be input in an array so if the user inputs 3, it will ask for a value to store in thearray, and then the program asks for input again, "input a number".

If the user inputs a value that is already stored in thearray, it should display for example "the number you input is stored already in array".

---

My professor gives this task to us, and he said that we should only be using  array and for loop. I'm new to this computer programming currently studying Programming  1st year college. It would be great if someone could help me.

```
int main()
{
   int Array[50], i, Number;
   int cont;

  printf("\nPlease Enter Number of elements in an array  :  ");
  scanf("%d", &Number);

  printf("\nPlease Enter %d elements of an Array \n", Number);
  for (i = 0; i < Number; i++)
   {
     scanf("%d", &Array[i]);

   }
 printf("ENTER NUMBER: ");
 scanf("%d", &cont);

 if(cont = Array[0]){
    printf("the number you input is stored in array# %d", Array[1]);
 }


}
```

the expected output should belike this

```
Please Enter Number of elements in an array: 3
Please Enter 3 elements of an Array
10
20
30
ENTER NUMBER:20

the number you input is stored in array# 1
```

But the output in my code is.

```
Please Enter Number of elements in an array: 3
Please Enter 3 elements of an Array
10
20
30
ENTER NUMBER:20

the number you input is stored in array# 20
```

Comment: You should loop over your array in its bounds and check every value itself. If you found the value, break the loop and print the index-variable. Also `for (i = 0; i < Number; i++)` is a dangerous statement if the user enters a number > 50 since your `Array` only contains 50 Elements.

Comment: Can you explain what you expect this code to do:  `if(cont = Array[0]){
    printf("the number you input is stored in array# %d", Array[1]);
 }`

Comment: `cont = Array[0]` -> `cont == Array[0]`. But there are most likely mor errors.

Comment: @AlexLop. if the user input an equal value to the array it will print the code bellow, im kinda still newbie to programming.

Comment: @Trickzter thanks men you just save me :) <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a common bug in your program here:

```
 if(cont = Array[0]){
    printf("the number you input is stored in array# %d", Array[1]);
 }
```

you are overwriting `cont` with `Array[0]`. What you meant to say is:

```
 if(cont == Array[0]){
    printf("the number you input is stored in array# %d", Array[1]);
 }
```

Also, you shouldn't only check if the number (`cont`) matches the first entry in the array, but all entries, like such:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Number; ++i) {
     if(cont == Array[i]){
        printf("the number you input is stored in array# %d", i);
        break;
     }
}
```

If the number is not found nothing is printed.

Comment: thank you so much, but can you tell me what the codes look should be?

Comment: @Seonix Just replace your "if(cont = Array[0]){..." with what I said "for (int i = 0; i < Number; ++i) {..."

Comment: okay thanks u just save my life :) still im noob at programming xD

Comment: i have a second question to you, if my professor accepts the while loop can you send me the while loop youre talking about? btw how do make this thread answered? xD

Comment: @Seonix There are no while loops involved in the question or solution. I'm not sure what you're talking about. See this answer https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: ops sorry it was not you, and thanks for the answer

Comment: can i ask another question?

Comment: @Seonix Sure you can. Create another question, make sure to follow the guidelines for a good question as outlined here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Also make sure you have done your research (or put in some effort of your own) before asking.

Comment: if i want to do it like while the user inputs the same value its gonna run the code that you gave to me, who do i do that? does it involve another kind of loop like while loop? do while?

Comment: okay thanks for the info im sure this is my last question. I'm just little bit confused over looping sorry for bothering you so much. its okay if you ignore my question u got my point anyways :) <3

Comment: @Seonix If what you're asking is How do I make sure the user inputs no duplicates, then you also need to check if the value is in array (use the same for loop I provided) just after the scanf call